# php mvc site resource path problems

Tags: php, html, model-view-controller

I am building php mvc site and for routing I use regex matching.

But I have problem when url route is (for example /news/1) more then one slashes after app root. Then all reqources are mising on rendered page (css, js and images)

I have found out that relative paths are problem, I have tried absolute paths using apache super globals DOCUMENT_ROOT but it still does not work.

The page that is rendered deeper in url (has more slashes ) simply does not see resources.

What would be soultion?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should not be experiencing these problems (with static assets like images, js etc) if you have made a correct setup. Are you using rewrites to force all requests being handled by a single file at your document root? Have a look at the Zend Frameworks apache directives in the .htaccess file as a quick setup quide.

Comment: yes all requests being handled by a single file at your document root, and in that file I am matching the routes by regex and redirect them to controller and in controller with switch statement I decide which View is going to be rendered. I am using Zend framework at all. I will have a look. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can create some global variable / configuration singleton class, which will store "base URL" of your web site. After that you will be able to build all passes to all static resources from that path.

Comment: I have create some, for full website url and for full document uri and use then on all places but still does not work. Thanks

Comment: Then probably there are some problems in rewrite module configuration.